# How to retrieve the latest tweet of a particular user in windows mobile 7.1?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, twitter

I have a textbox to get the user name from the user and am trying to retrieve his latest tweet from my application and its not working. When i try to get all the tweets of a user using a list box its working fine.
I tried this code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient twitter = new WebClient();
        twitter.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(twitter_DownloadStringCompleted);
        twitter.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=" + username.Text));

    }

    void twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        if (e.Error != null)
            return;

        XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

        //trying something
        var message = from tweet in xmlTweets.Descendants("status")
                      select tweet.Element("text").Value;

        textBlock1.Text = message.ToString();
```

}

the output : System.Linq.Enumerable+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var message = (from tweet in xmlTweets.Descendants("status")
                      select tweet.Element("text").Value).FirstOrDefault();

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
   textBlock1.Text = message.ToString();
```